# React Component state based on URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large website which has many sub websites under the main one. I have a `SubNav` that shows the name of the company's page we are currently visiting. As the user navigates between pages it should update the `SubNav` with the name.

This is what I have tried but to no avail.

Main Parent Root Component.

```
class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  state = { companySelected: "Main Company" };

   // this should update the company and name the SubNav bar 
  updateSelectedCompany = companySelected => {
    console.log("updated selected", companySelected);
    this.setState({ companySelected: companySelected });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <SubNav companySelected={this.state.companySelected} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} />
            <Route
              path="/company/1"
              component={SubCompany1}
              exact={true}
              updateSelectedCompny={this.companySelected}
            />
            <Route
              path="/company/2"
              component={SubCompany2}
              exact={true}
            />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The SubCompany1 Page looks like this:

```
class SubCompany1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ companySelected: "Sub Company 1" });
    console.log("Did Mount Sub Company1");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sub Company 1</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this possible to pass each time a page is visited? I'm quite new to react and not entirely sure the best way to pass state between components.

Comment: Hi Justin, see my solution below, that should be sufficient to stop the components from needlessly re-rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `componentDidMount()` and `shouldComponentUpdate()`

### AppRouter

```
class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  state = { companySelected: "Main Company" };

  updateSelectedCompany = companySelected => {
    this.setState({ companySelected: companySelected });
  };

  //if condition evaluates to true, component will update and re-render. if false, no re-render.
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
     return this.state.companySelected !== nextState.companySelected
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <SubNav companySelected={this.state.companySelected} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} />
            <Route
              path="/company/1"
              component={() => <SubCompany1 updateSelectedCompany={this.updateSelectedCompany} />}
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

### Subpage

```
class SubCompany1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.updateSelectedCompany("Sub Company 1");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sub Company 1</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your function `updateSelectedCompany` to child component

```
<Route
  exact={true}
  path="/company/1"
  component={() => <SubCompany1 updateSelectedCompany={this.updateSelectedCompany} />}
/>
```

Then call it there, which will change the state inside `AppRouter` component

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.updateSelectedCompany("Sub Company 1");
}
```

Comment: this seems to work but I'm getting an error: `Maximum update depth exceeded` is that because I'm using ComponentDidMount?

Comment: @Justin strange, do you have any other logic in your SubCompany1 component?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo nope just exactly what is show here. No further logic - but it looks like the components keep re-rendering